# Angular component not working after router.navigate method is called?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have a method that calls the `router.navigate` method that's supposed to redirect the user to our logout component:

```
private async logout(): Promise<void> {
this.sessionDataStore.logoutClicked = true;
console.log('Calling logout from error modal. ' + this.sessionDataStore.logoutClicked);
this.router.navigate([RoutingType.logout])


}
```

It switches the route like it is supposed to but my logout component that it is redirected to doesn't end up doing anything. When I manually type the route the component works as it supposed to. I'm struggling to find out why.

Here is my `logout` component.ts that I want loaded:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-logout',
  templateUrl: './logout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logout.component.scss']
})
export class LogoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscriptions = new Subscription();

  constructor(
    private oauthService: OAuthService,
    private userSessionService: UserSessionService,
    private sessionDataStore: SessionDataStoreService) {    
  }
  
  public oidcLogout: string;
  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('Logging out the user.');
    if (this.sessionDataStore.logoutClicked) {
      if (this.sessionDataStore.sessionId != null &&
        this.sessionDataStore.sessionId.length > 0) {
        this.subscriptions.add(this.userSessionService.EndSession(this.sessionDataStore.sessionId)
          .pipe(first()).subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Logout button clicked');
            this.oauthService.logOut(false);
            this.afterSessionEnded();
          }));
      }
    }
    else {
      if (this.sessionDataStore.sessionId != null &&
        this.sessionDataStore.sessionId.length > 0) {
        this.subscriptions.add(this.userSessionService.EndSession(this.sessionDataStore.sessionId)
          .pipe(first()).subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Browser/tab closed');
            this.oauthService.logOut(true);
            this.afterSessionEnded();
          }));
      }
    }
  }

  private async afterSessionEnded(): Promise<void> {
    this.oidcLogout = this.oauthService.logoutUrl + '?id_token_hint=' + this.oauthService.getIdToken();
    await this.oauthService.revokeTokenAndLogout();
    // reset storage
    this.sessionDataStore.logoutClicked = false;
    this.sessionDataStore.permissions = null;
    this.sessionDataStore.sessionId = null;
    this.sessionDataStore.userTimeoutInMinutes = null;
    console.log('Logged out');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this from outside angular zone? You can test this with NgZone service which has a method to test this.

Comment: @pascalpuetz can you give a quick example?

Comment: Why would you put that logic that logs the user out in a component init member, relying on navigation and component init to finish in order for them to be logged out.

Comment: @JadenAdams In your `logout()` method, directly before you navigate, write `console.log('Is in zone:', NgZone.isInAngularZone())`. What does the console log say? If it is outside angular zone, send the navigate call back to the zone by wrapping it in `this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate([RoutingType.logout]))` (in this case you need to inject the NgZone in your constructor).

Comment: @pascalpuetz calling `isInAngularZone()` did in fact return true. Still having issues figuring out why my logout component logic will not fire.

Comment: That is indeed strange. Can you maybe provide a minimum reproductive example on StackBlitz so I can take a closer look? From your code alone this looks like it should work as intended, though I'd suggest moving the logout logic to its own service and navigate after logging out through that service. Still, your code generally should work as far as I can see.